# Can Windows Workflows be wrapped into a Web Service so that any type of client can trigger it?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm experienced on the .Net platform, but I have never had to use Windows Workflows.

I'm at the point that I now need to know something about it, and i'm trying to wrap a workflow into a simple web service (SOAP).  Is this possible?

I can't find any good examples or articles on the web about this.  I'm also not really sure how it works if you need to have a long running workflow that needs to be suspended for a while, as in a a couple of days.

Were using the latest .Net 4.0 framework..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. WF and WCF are integrated very well using [Workflow Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_introtowfservices.aspx).